# Integer type casting in Qml?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I was trying to type cast a value from float to int in Qml.
How does that work??

```
text:int(todecimal(score))
```

For instance  score holds 9.8 or 5.3 . I want to make it 9 and 5.

Comment: NO,it is an attribute I would like to change in .qml file !

Comment: Oh, thats because my project is a combination of cpp and qml

Comment: This question is about QML.

Comment: yes @Sercan sir

Comment: Can you test the answer below and share the result?

Answer (score 1):

To convert a text input to integer in QML, use the following method. The following method is used to convert string expression to integer.

```
text:parseInt(textInput.text)
```

Try the solution below:

```
text:parseInt(score)
```

Comment: yeah I had a function which returned the value in decimal , which I wanted to convert to the lowest rounded integer. 9.8 to 9 and 9.2 to 9 . Now it is working fine :)